# Can I use next-auth to execute a one-time OAuth2 signin - only to get an access-token?

Tags: next.js, oauth, linkedin-api, next-auth

I've been working on a web app that connects with LinkedIn. The app authentication itself is done using Supabase Auth (without any adapters). Still, to make my life easier, I chose next-auth to make users connect their LinkedIn accounts to the web app.

I only need the OAuth2 access token for doing any particular LinkedIn operation. The token's TTL (Time To Live) is set to two months, so I need to 'signin' again only after that period of time.

[Screenshot of OAuth2 TTL LinkedIn Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehKua.png)

I save the token to a 'tokens' table connected to the user's ID by returning it in the session (so I save it client-side)

Here's my next-auth API route (`/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts`):

```js
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    LinkedInProvider({
      clientId: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: 'r_liteprofile w_member_social',
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }: { session: any; token: JWT; user: any }) {
      // Send access token to the client (to then save it in the database)
      session.user.token = token.accessToken;
      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

#### The Problem

When I sign out using async signOut() the logged-in LinkedIn account remains saved so as soon as I
async signIn(), the token doesn't get regenerated as it still sees the account as the previous one (rightly so, since it sees it as a login method).

#### The Question

Is there a way to use next-auth as a 'one-time login' method? Otherwise, I'd need to create all the LinkedIn auth workflow manually - which would be quite painful lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can't actually do that using next-auth by itself. In the end I custom created my own auth flow, using the LinkedIn docs.

They tend to be not as precise as I'd like, still after a while you figure them out!